# MassActions not working return js error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I m creating a custom module and everything is working fine except the mass actions. I know that i must have missed some setting ;) but i cant figure out where. Here is the grid config code:

service_index_listing.service_index_listing_data_source
            service_index_listing.service_index_listing_data_source
        
        service_columns
        
            
                add
                Add New Service
                primary
                */*/new
            
        
    
    
        
            ServiceGridDataProvider
            service_index_listing_data_source
            block_id
            id
            
                
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider
            
        
    
    
        
            
                ui/grid/toolbar
            
        
        
            
                
                    Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks
                    dataGridActions
                    
                        
                        
                        service_index_listing
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        service_index_listing.service_index_listing.service_columns
                    
                    Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns
                    dataGridActions
                
            
        
        
            
                
                    Magento_Ui/js/grid/search/search
                    dataGridFilters
                    service_index_listing.service_index_listing_data_source
                    service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips
                    
                        service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks
                        current.search

```
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <filterRange name="service_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">service_id</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterInput name="from">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
            <filterInput name="to">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput>
        </filterRange>
        <filterInput name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterInput>        

        <filterSelect name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">is_active</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select...</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disabled</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Published</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSelect>
        <filterRange name="creation_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\DateRange">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">creation_time</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterDate name="from">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterDate>
            <filterDate name="to">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterDate>
        </filterRange>
        <filterRange name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Filters\Type\DateRange">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">update_time</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterDate name="from">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">from</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">from</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">From</item>
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterDate>
            <filterDate name="to">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">to</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">to</item>
                        <item name="placeholder" xsi:type="string" translate="true">To</item>
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MM/dd/YYYY</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterDate>
        </filterRange>
    </filters>

    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.service_index_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">service_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="service/index/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="disable">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Disable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="service/index/massDisable"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="enable">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="service/index/massEnable"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>


    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.service_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">bottom</item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="20" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">20</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="30" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">30</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="50" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">50</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="100" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">100</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="200" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">200</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="service_columns">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
            </item>
            <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.service_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">service_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="service_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="shortdesc">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Short Description</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="display_order">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Display Order</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>        

    <column name="is_active">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Webilize\Service\Model\Service\Source\IsActive</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="creation_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">70</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="update_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Webilize\service\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ServiceActions">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">service_id</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">90</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

And the di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Webilize\Service\Api\Data\ServiceInterface" type="Webilize\Service\Model\Service" />
    <virtualType name="ServiceGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="ServiceGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Webilize\Service\Model\ResourceModel\Service\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">ServiceGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Webilize\Service\Model\ResourceModel\Service\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">webilize_service</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Webilize\Service\Model\ResourceModel\Service</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="service_index_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Webilize\Service\Model\ResourceModel\Service\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

When i click on any mass action (delete, disable, enable) it returns following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
    at UiClass.applyAction (massactions.js:52)
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (knockout.js:3863)
    at HTMLLIElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4624)
    at HTMLLIElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4292)
    enter code here
```

I am following [this blog](https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-part-5-adminhtml/)

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you selections provider is not correct.
Try to replace this line:

```
<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">service_index_listing.service_index_listing.service_columns.ids</item>
```

Because your columns component has name `service_columns` (`<columns name="service_columns">`), not `service_index_columns`